# Anylogic: how to send order to specific agent?

Tags: variables, events, parameters, anylogic, agent

I am rather new at Anylogic and I have these populations of agents:

- Customer (parameters: name, latitude, longitude)
- Terminal (parameters: name, latitude, longitude)
- Order (parameters: Customer, Terminal)
- Truck (statechart to first moveTo order.terminal and then to order.customer)

For every different terminal (I have 5) there is a different order rate per customer. So, I created (within Customer) five schedules for the rate of orders for every terminal. Now I want to create an event in Customer to create orders (one event per terminal). I have this now for the terminial with the name terminalA:

```
Order order = new Order(this, terminal.name("terminalA"));
Truck truck = getNearestAgentByRoute(filter(main.trucks,
            v -> v.inState(Truck.Free)));
if (truck != null)          
    send(order, truck);
```

However, the part *terminal.name("terminalA")* does not work, as it can not be resolved to a variable. How do I create an order per terminal and tell Anylogic what terminal (with what name) it should create orders for?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Kind regards,
Ella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `terminal.name("terminalA")`, just use `terminalA` if you have named that specific agent as `terminalA`; otherwise you need to access them by index, such as `main.terminals(0)`. The parameter type inside the Order agent should be set to `Terminal`. For example, below I create an order agent with a lot of different parameters & variables, each with a custom type.

[image]

Edit. You also need to make sure that your agent list is not empty:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! However, when I use `terminalA`, I get the error "terminalA cannot be resolved to a variable". I think because "terminalA" is a name, which is one of the parameters from a Terminal (given via a database)?

Comment: Yes, you can use `terminals(0)` instead of `terminalA` if you know that it is the first of the Terminal agents.

Comment: Then I get _"The method terminals(int) is undefined for the type Customer"_, which I really don't understand, as that parameter type inside the Order agent is set on `Terminal`. If I click control space after I type `new Order()`, it also gives `Order(Customer customer, Terminal terminal)`, so I don't know why it is not working...

Comment: @Ella, please see the updated answer.

Comment: thanks for the elaborated answers! But since I loaded my Customers and Terminals from databases, they should not be empty... Do you know what else could be the problem?

Comment: @Ella, `main.terminals(0)`?

Comment: Now I don't get an error while building anymore so I think that should be it! Thank you!!!
(however when I try to run it I get an error while drawing animation frame (and something from roote.customers[0] that says "Not unique database value!"), but I think that is another problem